# Flutter: overwritte class method

Tags: flutter, methods, widget, overwrite

I have a Table().

The Table() contains a list of Row().

Each Row() contains a list of Widget().

If one of the widget change, I want to trigger the function `bool lastLineIsNotEmpty() {}`.

Goal: Overwritte the actual method of `TextField` with a method from the Table().

So instead of doing that:

`CTable(row: CRow(widget_list:[TextField(onChanged: lastLineIsNotEmpty)]))`

I want to do that:

```
CTable my_table = CTable(row: CRow(widget_list:[TextField()]))
for (w in row.widget_list) {
  w.onChanged = lastLineIsNotEmpty;
}
```

But that doesn't work so I don't know if someone has an advice on how to deal with that problematic.

I am facing:

```
Class 'TextField' has no instance setter 'onChanged='.
Receiver: Instance of 'TextField'
Tried calling: onChanged=Closure: (String) => dynamic from Function 'lastLineIsNotEmpty':.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created an example of how you can change `onTap` method for your `TextField` widgets. I think you can adjust it to your problem.

```
class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  void function1() {
    print("function1");
  }

  void function2() {
    print("function2");
  }

  late var pointer = function1;

  late List<TextField> widgets = [
    TextField(
      onChanged: (value) => pointer(),
    ),
    TextField(
      onChanged: (value) => pointer(),
    ),
    TextField(
      onChanged: (value) => pointer(),
    ),
    TextField(
      onChanged: (value) => pointer(),
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              ...widgets.map((e) => e).toList(),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    pointer = function2;
                  });
                },
                child: Text('Change Method'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```